# Fetching related object using LINQ and EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two objects that are linked by a foreign key relationship and I use DataModel to map the objects:

Event:1------*:Asset

I wrote a query that fetches all assets for a given [eventPublicId]

```
List<Asset> assetList =
    ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<Event, List<Asset>>
    (u => u.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PublicId == eventPublicId).Assets.ToList()).ToList();
```

My problem is that I had to call ToList() twice and this looks awkward. Also I had to use FirstOrDefault, but when I tried to use [Where] or anything else, it didn't compile.

Is there any other better way how this code can be rewritten?

This is RetryWithExpression signature for reference:

```
public static TValue RetryWithExpression<T, TValue>(Func<ObjectSet<T>, TValue> func, Int32 retryInfiniteLoopGuard = 0)
         where T : class
```

Comment: Why do you have to call `ToList()` twice? And what compiler errors did you get?

Comment: If I omit the first Assets.ToList, I get a compile error:Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.
If I omit the second ToList, at runtime I get connection not open error, but this is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify that the `func` parameter should return a `List<Asset>`, so the navigation property `event.Assets` does not fit the bill: It is an `EntityCollection<Asset>`, which *is not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type*. The *explicit* conversion `ToList()` creates the specified type.

Technically, to get rid of the ToList, you should use

```
ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<Event, EntityCollection<Asset>> ...
```

but I don't know if that meets your functional requirements.

Comment: This makes sense, but after trying the EntityCollection I get an error: “The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection”. This is probably by design because RetryWithExpression disposes the connection upon return. RetryWithExpression does not support differed execution because I had to do a workaround to integrate The Transient Fault Handling Application Block, which unfortunately does not fully support EF and I have to manage the connection explicitly. Looks like I will have to do it using ToList. Thanks!